# Woo commerce customer see custom product price

Tags: wordpress, function, filter

Please provide some solution on this conditions.

Retailer adds a price x, admin has added a commission of 10% so the customer will see x+10% price. But when the product is sold the 10% deduction id done on the total price.

For example:

```
Retailer price - 500

Admin commission 10% - 50 

Customer purchase price is - 550
```

When distribution of price is done it is 55 to admin (10% of the customer purchase price) and retailer 495   (remaining amount)
need a solution so as retailer gets the price entered of 500

Comment: Where's the code that performs the math above?

Answer (score 0):

Please show some code. This must be a wrong mathematical calculation. If you add 10% to the product and then you want to subtract that 10% you added you just can't subtract 10% because it wont be the results you are expecting.

The approach I would taken as multiplying the retailers price by 1.1 is the same as adding 10%. You can the divide the total amount by 1.1

Like this:

500 * 1.1 = 550

550 / 1.1 = 500

Hope this works!